# C++ Linker Errors

Tags: c++

So I tried to divide my game into multiple files. I get these errors:

```
1>item.obj : error LNK2005: "private: static class sf::Image ctile::itile" (?itile@ctile@@0VImage@sf@@A) already defined in character.obj
1>item.obj : error LNK2005: "class cmap maps" (?maps@@3Vcmap@@A) already defined in character.obj
1>item.obj : error LNK2005: "class cmainchar mainch" (?mainch@@3Vcmainchar@@A) already defined in character.obj
1>item.obj : error LNK2005: "class citemmanager itemmanager" (?itemmanager@@3Vcitemmanager@@A) already defined in character.obj
1>item.obj : error LNK2005: "private: static class sf::Image citem::iitem" (?iitem@citem@@0VImage@sf@@A) already defined in character.obj
1>item.obj : error LNK2005: "private: static class sf::Image cspell::ispell" (?ispell@cspell@@0VImage@sf@@A) already defined in character.obj
1>item.obj : error LNK2005: "class sf::RenderWindow App" (?App@@3VRenderWindow@sf@@A) already defined in character.obj
1>item.obj : error LNK2005: "class sf::View View" (?View@@3V0sf@@A) already defined in character.obj
1>main.obj : error LNK2005: "private: static class sf::Image ctile::itile" (?itile@ctile@@0VImage@sf@@A) already defined in character.obj
1>main.obj : error LNK2005: "class cmap maps" (?maps@@3Vcmap@@A) already defined in character.obj
1>main.obj : error LNK2005: "class cmainchar mainch" (?mainch@@3Vcmainchar@@A) already defined in character.obj
1>main.obj : error LNK2005: "class citemmanager itemmanager" (?itemmanager@@3Vcitemmanager@@A) already defined in character.obj
1>main.obj : error LNK2005: "private: static class sf::Image citem::iitem" (?iitem@citem@@0VImage@sf@@A) already defined in character.obj
1>main.obj : error LNK2005: "private: static class sf::Image cspell::ispell" (?ispell@cspell@@0VImage@sf@@A) already defined in character.obj
1>main.obj : error LNK2005: "class sf::RenderWindow App" (?App@@3VRenderWindow@sf@@A) already defined in character.obj
1>main.obj : error LNK2005: "class sf::View View" (?View@@3V0sf@@A) already defined in character.obj
1>map.obj : error LNK2005: "private: static class sf::Image ctile::itile" (?itile@ctile@@0VImage@sf@@A) already defined in character.obj
1>map.obj : error LNK2005: "class cmap maps" (?maps@@3Vcmap@@A) already defined in character.obj
1>map.obj : error LNK2005: "class cmainchar mainch" (?mainch@@3Vcmainchar@@A) already defined in character.obj
1>map.obj : error LNK2005: "class citemmanager itemmanager" (?itemmanager@@3Vcitemmanager@@A) already defined in character.obj
1>map.obj : error LNK2005: "private: static class sf::Image citem::iitem" (?iitem@citem@@0VImage@sf@@A) already defined in character.obj
1>map.obj : error LNK2005: "private: static class sf::Image cspell::ispell" (?ispell@cspell@@0VImage@sf@@A) already defined in character.obj
1>map.obj : error LNK2005: "class sf::RenderWindow App" (?App@@3VRenderWindow@sf@@A) already defined in character.obj
1>map.obj : error LNK2005: "class sf::View View" (?View@@3V0sf@@A) already defined in character.obj
1>spell.obj : error LNK2005: "private: static class sf::Image ctile::itile" (?itile@ctile@@0VImage@sf@@A) already defined in character.obj
1>spell.obj : error LNK2005: "class cmap maps" (?maps@@3Vcmap@@A) already defined in character.obj
1>spell.obj : error LNK2005: "class cmainchar mainch" (?mainch@@3Vcmainchar@@A) already defined in character.obj
1>spell.obj : error LNK2005: "class citemmanager itemmanager" (?itemmanager@@3Vcitemmanager@@A) already defined in character.obj
1>spell.obj : error LNK2005: "private: static class sf::Image citem::iitem" (?iitem@citem@@0VImage@sf@@A) already defined in character.obj
1>spell.obj : error LNK2005: "private: static class sf::Image cspell::ispell" (?ispell@cspell@@0VImage@sf@@A) already defined in character.obj
1>spell.obj : error LNK2005: "class sf::RenderWindow App" (?App@@3VRenderWindow@sf@@A) already defined in character.obj
1>spell.obj : error LNK2005: "class sf::View View" (?View@@3V0sf@@A) already defined in character.obj
```

Comment: Rather than starting with *your game*, I suggest trying to take a simple "hello world" style application and split it into two or more files. That way you can (a) post the code here as an example, and (b) understand the important concepts more easily. We can't help you debug your code with only a list of error messages.

Answer (score 4):

You probably have your method definitions in .h files. As a result, you have many copies of a single definition in your

Keep the declarations in the .h file with include guards:

```
#ifndef SOMETHING_H_
#define SOMETHING_H_

class Something {
public:
    int foo();
};

#endif // SOMETHING_H_
```

and the method definitions in the .cpp file:

```
#include "Something.h" 

int Something::foo() {
    return 5;
}
```

Comment: I have header guards, and there are no methods in my headers.

Comment: Then you're doing something wrong. Look at the first error: `1>item.obj : error LNK2005: "private: static class sf::Image ctile::itile" (?itile@ctile@@0VImage@sf@@A) already defined in character.obj` basically means that this class is defined BOTH in `item.obj` (result of compiling item.cpp, I pressume) and in `character.obj`. This is usually "achieved" by omitting include guards and I don't have any idea how you could've done it by accident otherwise. Can you post those files (2x .cpp + header with that class)?

Comment: I found out the problem was that I was declaring the instances in the header.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that definitions of your class member functions are placed in header files. So, the same definitions go to separate translation units.

Also, use [include guards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) in your header files.

Comment: I really want to downvote your answer. Maybe he doesn't have include guards, but the errors come from the linker, so include guards won't solve it.

Comment: @ybungalobill: LNK2005 is a multiple definition error. So if the OP is including a header file without include guards multiple times within the same translation unit the linker will throw this error. Adding include guards will fix this problem.

Comment: @ybungalobill Completely agree with you. I corrected the answer. It seems I need to go to sleep :-)

Comment: @Praetorian I would agree with @ybungalobill. I guess, redefinition problem is detected by compiler, not linker.

Comment: OK, now I was understand what @ybungalobill was saying, my apologies.